# calculating the last non-zero digit of a factorial- why does my code pass some tests but fail others?

Tags: python, factorial

I am writing code to solve the following codewars question: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5f79b90c5acfd3003364a337/train/python

My idea is to take all the integers from `1 to n`, and take the last digit of each of these integers (bar 0), multiply them together, and return the 'last' non-zero digit of the result:

```
def last_digit(n):
    factorials = []
    factorials_n = 1
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
        i = str(i)
        i = i[::-1]
        for j in i:
            if j == "0":
                break
            factorials.append(j)
            break              


    # at this point factorials contains the first non-zero integers of each integer in reverse
    for i in factorials:
        factorials_n = factorials_n * int(i)

    factorials_n = str(factorials_n)
    factorials_n = factorials_n[::-1]


    for i in factorials_n:
        if i != "0":
            return int(i)
```

The code passes a number of tests, but fails for `387` `(returns 6, should be 2)` and `1673` `(returns 2 should be 4)`. I've tried doing print statements as debug but the code seems fine, perhaps it's the logic that fails at some point- any ideas?

Comment: What is the smallest input n where the result is not correct?

Comment: Have you verified that the contents of `factorials` are correct? I suspect that they aren't.

Comment: You need to use some maths, not brute force.

Comment: Or maybe first brute force to find an obviously correct solution as reference, and then math to make it efficient while staying correct.

Comment: @mkrieger1 for smaller values of n, factorials is correct, so I imagine for larger ones they are too!

Comment: You also imagined that your entire code was correct but it isn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the logic. Since you are dropping all the cases where the number ends in 0, we do not arrive at the correct answer.

Consider 2 x 8 x 30. To get the last digit of the factorial, multiplying last digits would suffice, but to find the last non zero digit, you have to evaluate 2 x 8 x 3
instead.

Using [this](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4919?#comment-99973) solution as a reference, here's what you can do:

```
def last_digit(n):
    # factorials = []
    # factorials_n = 1
    last = 1
    d2 = 0
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
       
        ii = i
        print(ii)
        while(ii%2==0):
            d2 +=1
            ii = ii/2
        
        while(ii%5==0):
            d2 -=1
            ii = ii/5
        print(d2)
        last = (last * ii)%10
        print(last)
    
    for i in range(0,d2):
        last = (last *2)%10

    return int(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code passes the test cases for numbers uptill 24, it fails when the non-zero digit from 25! gives an incorrect answer which get propogated forward for the numbers after it.

And also we can simply use the modulo operator to get the very last digit instead of converting it into a string
Example: `1234 % 10` equals `4` (which is the last digit)

My solution:

```
def last_digit(n):

    factorial = 1
    
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
    
        # compute the factorial
        prod = factorial * i
        
        # keep dividing the product by 10 until the last digit is a !0 digit
        while prod % 10 == 0:
            prod = prod // 10
            
        # only store the last 3 digits of the computed product.
        # You can keep more digits to get accurate results for
        # when the numbers are higher than 10000
        factorial = prod % 1000
    
    # return the last digit
    return factorial % 10
```

As i said earlier, when the last !0 digit from 24! (`6`) is multiplied with 25, it outputs 150 which after removing the 0 gives 5 but it instead should be 4. Hence, in order to solve this we keep at least the last 3 digits instead of only the last digit.

```
Example:   6 * 25 =   150 => 5 (last !0 digit)
         936 * 25 = 23400 => 4 (last !0 digit)
```

PS: !0 = non-zero

Comment: I'm not sure if keeping 3 instead of 1 digit will not run in the same kind of problem sooner or later.

Comment: It sure will run into the same problem but will work out for all the test cases mentioned in the problem statement for now

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for the solution it all makes sense. One question, why do we keep three digits, instead of keeping just 1? In my mind it won't influence any further multiplications? (As long as the one digit isn't a 0 of course- and it won't be based on your code!)

Comment: You can keep as many digits you want but 3 is the minimum to pass all the required test cases in the program. As I had explained earlier, multiplying with 3 digits will give you far more accurate non-zero last-digit than multiplying with only 1 digit. Similarly, multiplying with the whole-number(with all digits) will give you the most accurate result than with only 3 digits.